# React email client - Printing mail details affects page layout

Tags: reactjs, redux, html-email, email-client

I am working on email client, I am fetching emails from gmail. When I print email contents on page using

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: body.content }} />
```

It works fine but as you know email comes with inline css which is affecting my page UI, font sizes changes, div shrinks/expands.

To overcome this I used Iframe, and printing email contents to iframe, this solved my problem But I noticed that If I print email to Iframe, email itself is loosing some styling. Fonts look different in gmail, outlook and my email client.

Email looks almost similar in gmail and outlook but looks way different in my email client page.

Comment: Anyone please? I feel like stackoverflow is dying :( I hardly get answers.

Comment: Hey Amit--can we get some screenshots: expected output, actual output. And note which environment they are in (if you didn't know, Gmail and Outlook and web are very different environments). Gmail adds its own font, for example. Outlook doesn't accept much HTML/CSS.

Comment: 1) https://ibb.co/QJzP13b
2) https://ibb.co/6ZYfCcT    Links to screenshots, I have opened 2 different email and you can clearly see emails list items are shrinked in one email and looks fine in other one.

Comment: It's still not clear in my mind what the specific problem is. 'They look different' isn't clear enough. Firstly, what email environment are these screenshots in (OS & version? Browser/app/software? Email client & version?). Second, you haven't marked what you are expecting the output to be. For example, the fonts look the same to me, and the two screenshot layouts look very similar

Comment: 1) I am creating outlook clone (email client) using reactjs in chrome,2) You can see what i mean in this new images 1) https://ibb.co/Z60mV2R
2) https://ibb.co/8svzb81 Open this 2 images in 2 seperate tabs and, you will notice the difference.

Comment: Ok good, we have the specific issue. So now, what is the coding difference between the two?

Comment: Same code is there for both of the emails and others too. Only difference I see is css that coming with those emails. I want to know How can i ignore that css and not let it affect my page UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Gmail does, as an example, to separate each email's specific CSS, is to add a prefix to all classes and styles. This prefix is unique to each email.

So a class of "hide" might become `class="m_-8236917340709346301hide"`, and the corresponding style in the embedded CSS would also change, i.e. `.m_-8236917340709346301hide{display:none!important}`.

Now the email CSS is separate from the rest of the page. You may also need a CSS reset.

Comment: Yeh, this is the right way to do it. This is bit of a work, But to get rid of iframe I am ready to do it. This solutions would surely work except for css on html elements itself like `<h1>`  `h1 { color: "red" }`, In this cases I need to change css to `.m_13123213h1 { color: red" }` and add this class to html element `<h1 class="m_13123213h1" >`